# objective c compare two date strings in NSDate

Tags: objective-c, iphone, datepicker, nsdate

Hi I am having two date as string , that is assigned to two labels,

one label holds current date string, that is may 29, 2010

similarly the other date will be selected by user in this same format, i need to check the user date is present, past , or future. by comparing with current date string.

please provide some sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994855/comparing-dates-in-iphone-programming

Answer (score 3):

simple...
Comparing Dates

- – isEqualToDate:
- – earlierDate:
- – laterDate:
- – compare:

These are all in NSDate documentation which u can access by pressing the help button on menu and then selecting Developer Documentation...type in search NSDate.then what u need is compare.....

IF AND ONLY IF u want it to be present...put a check as special case if the dd/MM/YYYY are same, say its a present value...OR USE isEqualToDate......
IF the comparison with current date gives a negative value....its future..
IF the comparison with current date gives a positive value....its past...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I used to solve this problem:

```
[Lout setStringValue:mydates];
NSDate* dateDB = [NSDate date];
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];

//Create the dateformatter object
NSDateFormatter* formatterDate = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[formatterDate setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss"];

dateDB = [formatterDate dateFromString:value3];

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"date value = %@",[formatterDate stringFromDate:dateDB]]);

NSTimeInterval timeInt = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:dateDB];
timeInt = timeInt/60;
```

This code will give you elapsed time in minutes. (It will give a negative number if the "since" date is in the future.)