# How to compare two dates in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to compare the todays date and other date coming from my database. 
For example, 2011-03-25 compare it with 2011-02-25

How can i formate my database date as the NSDateFormatter require NSDdate datatype ?

Comment: From the looks of your question, your date coming from the database looks like they stored as strings.  If so and they will always in the format of yyyy-MM-dd, you can use the -isEqualToString forever with no problem.  But if you they are NSDate object see the answer from @Jhaliya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cocoa has couple of methods for this:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-DontLinkElementID_6)

in NSDate

– isEqualToDate:
– earlierDate:
– laterDate:
– compare:

When you use - (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDate *)anotherDate ,you get back one of these:

```
The receiver and anotherDate are exactly equal to each other, NSOrderedSame
The receiver is later in time than anotherDate, NSOrderedDescending
The receiver is earlier in time than anotherDate, NSOrderedAscending.
```

for more read the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994855/comparing-dates-in-iphone-programming)

Just go through the blog post, there are many date related utility functions.

http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2010/03/how-to-real-world-dates-with-the-iphone-sdk.ars/2

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
NSDate *date2 = [NSDate date];

if ([date1 compare: date2]==NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"YES");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtDates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000183-BCIDBADB

Isn't that the same on Iphone?

Answer (score 0):

If your date are string like year-month-day, you can just compare string:

```
 if ([date1 compare:string2]==NSOrderedAscending) {
 } else if ([date1 compare:string2]== NSOrderedDescending) {
 } else {
 }
```

It will works because fields in date are from most important to less, like a string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSDate compare: or timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate -- that'll get you started

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift**:

```
let date1 = NSDate() //some date
let date2 = NSDate() //another date

let firstDate = date1.earlierDate(date2)
let lastDate = date1.laterDate(date2)
```