# How to compare two strings in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Comparing dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994855/comparing-dates)
>   [How to compare two dates in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949416/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-objective-c)

i want to compare 2 strings who have a date format "11-06-2011" and "12-06-2011" for exemple.
 i want to see if the second date is greater than the first or not 
can you help me please ?

---

i tried this code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"];
    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:deparatureDateField.text];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:comebackDateField.text];
    [dateFormat release];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
    if(timeInterval >= 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attention" message:@"come back date should be greater" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

but i alwayse have an alert, NSTimeInterval timeInterval is alwayse NULL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find out if one date is larger than the other you'd have to do this:

```
NSString *string1 = @"11-06-2011";
NSString *string2 = @"12-06-2011";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:string1];
NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:string2];
[dateFormat release];

NSComparisonResult comparisonResult = [date1 compare:date2];

/*
NSComparisonResult can be either of these values:
 - NSOrderedAscending (-1) //if date1 < date2
 - NSOrderedSame (0)       //if date1 = date2
 - NSOrderedDescending (1) //if date1 > date2
*/
```

Alternatively (to `compare:`) you could use `timeIntervalSinceDate:` to get the actual time difference:

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
//timeInterval will be
// - nagative if ascending,
// - zero if same,
// - positive if descending
```

Comment: @Regexident @murat  thakyou but i think my question are not clear. I don't want to see if there are equal, i want to see if the second date is greater than the first or not

Comment: @user794317: updated my answer. See second snippet.

Comment: @Regexident thank you very much , but i alwayse have a trouble , i updated my question

Comment: @user794317: My bad. I got the date format string wrong. The `YYYY` got to be smallcase, `dd-MM-yyyy`, that is.

Comment: @user794317: I'm always mixing up the cases with those date formats. :P Btw, with a click on the green checkmark right beneath the vote you can accept the answer and mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends what you will do after comparison. If you want to keep date info as a string and compare the strings is

```
   [@"11-06-2011" isEqualToString: @"12-06-2011"]
```

is enough for you

Answer (score 0):

look at NSDates timeIntervalSinceNow, you can compare the time interval from both dates to see which one is the most recent etc.

```
NSTimeInterval *interval = [someDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

Comment: Why go the loop way, if there is `[date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2]` ;)